# Appending modified object to list in for loop -- only last modification is stored

Tags: python, list, variables, for-loop

I created a function that goes through a loop, creates variables, and appends them in a list.

```
    def function(self,RECORD):
        TEMP_LIST_RECORDS=[]
        #Depends the number of X, we got 10, 100,1000,10000 LOOPS
        LOOPS=int(math.pow(10,X_RANGE))
        DIGITS="%0"+str(X_RANGE)+"d"

        #Then we create the records and we add to the MYSQL data query
        for x in range (0,LOOPS):

            END_OF_NUMBER=DIGITS%x
            RECORD.DN=DN_NUMBER+str(END_OF_NUMBER)
            RECORD.GN=GN_NUMBER+str(END_OF_NUMBER)

            TEMP_LIST_RECORDS.append(RECORD)

        return TEMP_LIST_RECORDS
```

Explanation:
I pass an object called `RECORD` that has 2 properties, `DN` and `GN`.
These properties have this structure: 0000213123XX, where XX is a two-digit number.
What need to do is generate values for XX in the range between 00 and 99, so the properties will be: 000021312300, 000021312301,...  Every time I append to the list a `RECORD`, the `RECORD` `DN` and `GN` change in the range.
As I explain later, during the loop, the numbers are found, but once the loop is finished, all objects in the list become the last one found.

Then all values returned in the list are:

```
000021312399
000021312399
000021312399
000021312399
000021312399
000021312399
000021312399
000021312399
```

But, if I put a print inside the loop:

```
def function(self,RECORD):
        TEMP_LIST_RECORDS=[]
        #Depends the number of X, we got 10, 100,1000,10000 LOOPS
        LOOPS=int(math.pow(10,X_RANGE))
        DIGITS="%0"+str(X_RANGE)+"d"

        #Then we create the records and we add to the MYSQL data query
        count=0
        for x in range (0,LOOPS):

            END_OF_NUMBER=DIGITS%x
            RECORD.DN=DN_NUMBER+str(END_OF_NUMBER)
            RECORD.GN=GN_NUMBER+str(END_OF_NUMBER)

            TEMP_LIST_RECORDS.append(RECORD)
            print TEMP_LIST_RECORDS[count].DN
            count+=1

        return TEMP_LIST_RECORDS
```

The result of the prints are:

```
000021312300
000021312301
000021312302
000021312303
000021312304
000021312305
000021312306
000021312307
...
```

Can anybody explain to me why? How do I solve this?

Comment: Don't use all caps for variable names.

Comment: also you have a bunch of undefined variables(or at least TEMP_LIST_RECORDS) ... but at a guess RECORD is a mutable datatype and you are changing it ...

Comment: The problem is you keep appending the _same_ `RECORD` to `TEMP_LIST_RECORDS` with the `TEMP_LIST_RECORDS.append(RECORD)` statement, so at the the list is just a bunch of references to the last value `RECORD` was given. You need to create a new and append a new `RECORD` each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question, I did post a update and hopefully someone can give me a solution :)

Comment: there's your solution.  @martineau gave it to you.

Comment: @Kein-Wai your question was quite clear.  i made a few minor edits to clean it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @martineau has commented, your problem is that you've appended to `TEMP_LIST_RECORDS` a bunch of references to the same object, `RECORD`.  Hence, when the loop is finished, the contents of the list are all the same.

This can be fixed with a one-line change to your code.  All you have to do is re-initialize `RECORD` inside each iteration of the loop (so each loop has a separate instance):

```
def function(self,RECORD):
    TEMP_LIST_RECORDS=[]
    #Depends the number of X, we got 10, 100,1000,10000 LOOPS
    LOOPS=int(math.pow(10,X_RANGE))
    DIGITS="%0"+str(X_RANGE)+"d"

    #Then we create the records and we add to the MYSQL data query
    for x in range (0,LOOPS):

        RECORD = GET_NEW_RECORD()  # THIS IS THE CHANGE.

        END_OF_NUMBER=DIGITS%x
        RECORD.DN=DN_NUMBER+str(END_OF_NUMBER)
        RECORD.GN=GN_NUMBER+str(END_OF_NUMBER)

        TEMP_LIST_RECORDS.append(RECORD)

    return TEMP_LIST_RECORDS
```

Of course, replace `GET_NEW_RECORD` with a call to the appropriate class.

Comment: Man, thank you very much, I understood now. I was passing the address who reference to the same record all time.